# Variable not assigning value to new variable

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two variable newdose and other is appDelegate variable the value in newdose is 50 but in appDelegate variable it shows zero.

```
float newdose=vacinedose;
appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Cost_Vaccination_Annually_No_Guarantee=newdose;
NSLog(@"After Dose Vaccine Dose is %.2f",newdose);
```

Comment: Are you saying that the log shown here logs 0?

Comment: NSLog(@"vacinedose %.2f", vacinedose);  make sure it is 50

Comment: yes it is 50 i have checked

Comment: Can you show the `vacinedose` declaration part?

Comment: Check if appDelegate variable is not nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your appDelegate variable. Do :

```
appDelegate=[UIApplication SharedApplication]
```

Comment: NSLog(@"Vaccine Dose is %.2f", vacinedose); try this. And check

Comment: it is showing value 45 while we NSLog(@"Vaccine Dose is %.2f",vacinedode)

Comment: Try :

float newdose=45;
appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Cost_Vaccination_Annually_No_Guarantee=newdose;
NSLog(@"After Dose Vaccine Dose is %.2f",newdose);

Try this code and see what is the output u getting?

Comment: thanks actually i did not initialized appDelegate=[UIApplicationSharedApplication] it workd for me now thanks

Comment: @DeveloperIOS: You shuld not accept an incorrect/semi-correct answer. Istead you can post your own answer and accept it.